# CSS Resize images to fit in a container

Tags: html, css

I want to fit images in a container with different images size like this :

**Example :**

**1. Full size in a container with bigger size.**

[image]

**2. Middle in a container with horizontal size.**

[image]

**3. Middle in a container with vertical size.**

[image]

Check out an example from this [link](https://fancy.com/things/1068560261947855337/GAEMS-Vanguard-Personal-Gaming-Environment?utm=timeline_featured)

Comment: please provide your code in jsfiddle or in snippet.

Comment: Not sure if spam or actually a programming question, since no code is provided...

Comment: You got a point man @GusstavvGil but however i posted the answer

Comment: @GusstavvGil [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7y26ft5/)

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7y26ft5/2/)

Comment: Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/w7y26ft5/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gautam said, you need to use

```
max-height:100%;
max-width: 100%;
```

So you can define a class for the containers

```
.container
{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

And a class for the images

```
.maxsize
{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The `display:flex;` property makes the container easier to config, so you can center the contents faster. You can remove the `border` property, it's only for easier viewing of the container edges.
Hope it helps.

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7y26ft5/4/)

Comment: First image can fit in full size?

Comment: use `:first-child` @ButterToast

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. You can make the container any size you want (i've put 50px to make it easier to view). The images will fit accordingly (retaining the aspect ratio). If the size is a square and the image is a square then it'll fully fit. If the image is a rectangle then it'll fit on the largest axis.

Answer (score 1):

Just set this property on the parent container.

```
background-size : contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This tells the browser to make sure that the image does not exceed the size of the parent container.

Comment: I've tried your code, Can you help me fix that? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7y26ft5/1/)

Comment: Sure, you need to keep a few small things in mind. One, in order for an image to be able to auto-scale based on the parent container, the parent container needs to have an explicit width and height. I update the fiddle to run and you can adjust the dimensions of the parent container to whatever you like. https://jsfiddle.net/svp9Lp63/1/

Answer (score 1):

this is easy to do

just align your image to the center and

use 
`max-height:100%`
and 
`max-width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

As Robert mentioned:

```
background-size : contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

But be sure to add:

```
background-position: center;
```

Then it will remain within the boundaries of the container and be centered.

Comment: This assumes you are using background images instead of the img tag, then it would be a different story.

Comment: If this is helpful, please upvote or mark as the correct answer. It would contribute to my stackoverflow reputation. Good luck!